# Disable HammerJS swipe and drag events on computer? (i.e. disable on mouse events?)

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js found here:
  http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

and I set-up/create the Hammer object like this:

```
var hammertime = Hammer(document.body)
                      .on("pinchin drag swipe", function(event) {
                        var alpha_value = $( "#collide_alpha" ).slider( "option", "value" );
                        var beta_value = $( "#collide_beta" ).slider( "option", "value" );
                        if(alpha_value < 50) {
                          $( "#collide_alpha" ).slider( "value", ~~(+alpha_value+(event.gesture.distance/30)) );
                        } else if(alpha_value <= 100) {
                          $( "#collide_alpha" ).slider( "value", ~~(+alpha_value-(event.gesture.distance/30)) );
                        }
                        if(beta_value < 50) {
                          $( "#collide_beta" ).slider( "value", ~~(+beta_value+(event.gesture.distance/30)) );
                        } else if(beta_value <= 100) {
                          $( "#collide_beta" ).slider( "value", ~~(+beta_value-(event.gesture.distance/30)) );
                        }
                      });
```

After, I tried to do this:

```
// Try to disable the mouse movements on computer
hammertime.STOP_MOUSEEVENTS = true;
hammertime.NO_MOUSEEVENTS = true;
```

But that doesn't work, so how should I disable the events just for computers? but leave them active for iPhone and Android. I don't care about Windows 8 touch-screens at the moment so I don't mind that it would not work for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally try and detect if the device is a touch screen before firing hammer. Its better to only load when you need it rather than when you dont

One of the most supported ways off doing this is

```
var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
```

Then just wrap your hammer initialisation in

```
if(is_touch_device){
  // hammer stuff
}
```

Alternatively you could sniff the user agent if you only care for a few devices but this could be a bit clunky and prone to missing things.

Answer (score 1):

I use Modernizr to decide if I should run hammer:

```
     if ( Modernizr.touch )
     {
        $("#cr-stage").hammer().on( "swipeleft swiperight swipeup swipedown doubletap pinchin", gesture );
        $("#cr-stage").hammer().on( "release", releaseGesture );
     }
```

This is more reliable than user agent sniffing.